# [Safari/Chrome fatal Bug]HTML5 canvas not works for a specific case but Firefox does well

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, safari

I use html5 canvas to build a function-graph software.
There is a critical bug but I don't know what is going on.

That is, when I call:

```
yOFxGraph(plotFUNCinputYofX,-4,5,-4,4,"rgb(66,44,255)",1);
```

everything works good in Firefox26/Chrome32/Safari7 on Mac.

However, when I change **only one** tiny parameter like:

```
yOFxGraph(plotFUNCinputYofX,-5,5,-4,4,"rgb(66,44,255)",1);
```

the **graph** just **disappears in Chrome/Safari** but still **works good in Firefox**.

The entire code is below, could you please tell me how to solve it? Thank you very much. 
How could this bug just happen to major browsers!? regardless the code is so simple.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body onload="draw()">
    <script>
    function plotFUNCinputYofX(x) {return 1/Math.sin(x);}

    function draw() {
       yOFxGraph(plotFUNCinputYofX,-4,5,-4,4,"rgb(66,44,255)",1);
    }

    function yOFxGraph (func,xFrom,xTo,yFrom,yTo,color,thick) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth = thick;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;

        var Xunit = canvas.width/(xTo-xFrom);
        var Yunit = canvas.height/(yTo-yFrom);
        var samplingX=(xTo-xFrom)/400;/*I only sample 400 points whatever the scale is.*/
        var xx = xFrom;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0 , canvas.height-(func(xx)-yFrom)*Yunit);

        function pivoting(){
            xx+=samplingX;
            ctx.lineTo((xx-xFrom)*Xunit , canvas.height-(func(xx)-yFrom)*Yunit);
        }
        if(xFrom<xTo){while(xx<xTo){pivoting()}}
        else if(xFrom>xTo){while(xx>xTo){pivoting()}}
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    </script>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have found that when I reduce the sampling points from 400 to 255, Safari and Chrome will live again.
However, as reducing to 200 points, Safari strikes again and Chrome doesn't work properly either.
Is this something to do with GPU acceleration???

Comment: Or this is a issue of floating number computing of the Webkit engine?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but it seems a bug report is in order.

Comment: Yes, I did.
And still thinking some tricky ways to overcome this.

Comment: interesting; looking through your code now. For anybody else who wants a quick way to make changes, I put it in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Luy7L/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you found a difference in the way the browsers handle Infinity (or possibly huge values) when drawing.

First, let's note that by having -5 to 5, you allow the exact value x=0, which causes `1/sin(0)` which is `Infinity` (or with some floating point rounding errors, could be a hugely positive or negative value).

FireFox evidently ignores this. Perhaps it ignores the point but continues to stroke the rest of the line as if it wasn't there, or maybe it leaves it as a break in the line (which I would consider the correct, intuitive behaviour for NaNs).

But in Chrome and Safari, this Infinity or huge number causes the entire stroke to become invalid, therefore it does not draw any of it.

The simple fix is to ensure your value is sane. Here's a check which caps it to the bounds: (you may want to use wider bounds, or handle going off-screen differently)

```
var yy = func(xx);
if(!(yy>yFrom))yy=yFrom;
if(!(yy<yTo))yy=yTo;
ctx.lineTo((xx-xFrom)*Xunit , canvas.height-(yy-yFrom)*Yunit);
```

I have verified that this fixes the issue you are seeing in Chrome. I assume it applies to Safari too.

Comment: Hey Dave!
Thank you very much for analyzing and providing a solution.
I thought your analysis was reasonable. However, when I try to draw 1/sin(x+5) for a range x=-5~5, Safari and Chrome both work well.
That means, the cause of the issue might not be "divide by zero", instead, it seems like a random crash.
By the way, I have re-tested the 1/0. Javascript judged it "Infinity", but not "NaN".
What do you think??

Comment: Infinity can still be calculated by Javascript.
Like Infinity+3=Infinity.

Comment: Well in my analysis I'm treating NaN, infinity and super-large numbers interchangeably, since which specific one will be returned depends on the exact situation and built-up rounding errors. The essence is the same for all of them; it is a number which is, for all practical purposes, nonsensical. The drawing method is entirely justified in getting confused by it (maybe it is using fixed-point precision and very large numbers are causing an overflow). To work around it, clamp the values like I suggested in my answer and the problem will go away. To fix it, file a bug and wait (which you did).

Comment: also in fairness, yes, 1/0 is infinity and 0/0 is NaN. I got that bit wrong, but as I say, the rest of the analysis is still valid.

Comment: Hey,Dave!
Thanks, your analysis is awesome!
I used your idea and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Dave's idea, I finally edited my code as below:

```
/*Safari7 & Chrome32 canvas bug*/
var Y=canvas.height-(func(xx)-yFrom)*Yunit;
if(0<=Y&&Y<=canvas.height){ctx.moveTo(0 , Y);}
else if(Y>canvas.height){Y=canvas.height+1;ctx.moveTo(0 , Y);}
else if(Y<0){Y=-1;ctx.moveTo(0 , Y);}
/*Safari7 & Chrome32 canvas bug*/
function pivoting(){
    xx+=samplingX;
    /*Safari7 & Chrome32 canvas bug*/
    Y=canvas.height-(func(xx)-yFrom)*Yunit;
    if(0<=Y&&Y<=canvas.height){ctx.lineTo((xx-xFrom)*Xunit , Y);}
    else if(Y>canvas.height){Y=canvas.height+1;ctx.lineTo((xx-xFrom)*Xunit , Y);}
    else if(Y<0){Y=-1;ctx.lineTo((xx-xFrom)*Xunit , Y);}
    /*Safari7 & Chrome32 canvas bug*/
}
```

And everything works now!!

Thank you Dave.